# Derive Linear Regression, aka Derive Order 1 LMMSE Estimator

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation

Assume out estimator has the form:

$$\hat{Y} = aX+b$$

find the coefficients a and b that minimize the Mean square error for the estimate $\hat{Y}$, that is minimize $\text{MSE}(\hat{Y})$:

$$e = \text{MSE}(\hat{Y}) = E\Big[(Y-\hat{Y})^2\Big]$$

---

Ok, so I give it a try:

$$\frac{de}{da} = \frac{d}{da} E\Big[(Y-\hat{Y})^2\Big] = 0\tag{1}$$

$$\frac{de}{db} = \frac{d}{db} E\Big[(Y-\hat{Y})^2\Big] = 0\tag{2}$$

---

Solving for (1):

$$\text{Let}~U = Y - aX -b$$

$$E\Big[\frac{d}{da} U^2\Big] = 0$$

Applying chain rule:

$$E[2U\frac{dU}{da}]=0$$

$$E[U\frac{dU}{da}]=0$$

$$E[(Y-aX-b)(-X)] = 0$$

$$E[X^2]a + E[X]b = E[XY]\tag{3}$$

---

Solving for (2):

$$\text{Let}~U = Y - aX -b$$

$$E\Big[\frac{d}{db} U^2\Big] = 0$$

Applying chain rule:

$$E[2U\frac{dU}{db}]=0$$

$$E[U\frac{dU}{db}]=0$$

$$E[(Y-aX-b)(-1)]=0$$

$$E[Y-aX-b]=0$$

$$E[X]a+b=E[Y]\tag{4}$$

---

(3) and (4) gives me a system of equations that I can solve for a and b:

$$E[X^2]a + E[X]b = E[XY]\tag{3}$$

$$E[X]a+b=E[Y]\tag{4}$$

rearrange (4):

$$b=E[Y]-E[X]a\tag{5}$$

subst (5) into (3):

$$E[X^2]a + E[X](E[Y]-E[X]a) = E[XY]$$

$$E[X^2]a + E[X]E[Y]-E[X]E[X]a) = E[XY]$$

$$E[X^2]a + E[XY]-E[X^2]a = E[XY]$$

$$0 = 0$$

Now I know something is wrong because the book says the answer is:

$$a=\frac{E[XY] - E[X]E[Y]}{E[X^2]-(E[X])^2}$$

$$b=E[Y] - a E[X]$$

I'm Wondering why my system of equations is linearly dependent...and I can't solve it to get the book answer...

Answer (score 1):

solve (4) for b:

$$b = E[Y] - a E[X]\tag{5}$$

substitute (5) into (3):

$$E[X^2]a + E[X]\Big[E[Y]-aE[X]\Big] = E[XY]$$

$$E[X^2]a + E[X]E[Y] - a E[X]E[X] = E[XY]$$

$$E[X^2]a + E[X]E[Y] - a (E[X])^2 = E[XY]$$

$$a\Big[E[X^2]-  (E[X])^2\Big]  = E[XY] - E[X]E[Y]$$

$$a = \frac{E[XY] - E[X]E[Y]}{\Big[E[X^2]-  (E[X])^2\Big]}$$